# Scroll through Flutter Bottom Sheet

Tags: flutter

I'm using a Flutter modal bottom sheet to display some options for the user to select.
I have a `Column` with a list of `ListTile`s as the content of the bottom sheet.

My problem is that if I have more than 6 `ListTile`s, some are cut off and not displayed.

Is there a way to make the bottom Sheet scrollable?

Comment: You could show the code to analyze it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just change your `Column` into a `ListView`, like so:

```
return ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    ...
  ]
);
```

**What if I don't want the content of the sheet to be scrolled, but the sheet itself?**

If you want the user to be able to swipe up the bottom sheet to fill the screen, I'm afraid this isn't possible in the current implementation of the modular bottom sheet.

Answer (score 44):

I've found a solution implementing the code below

```
void _showBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  builder: (context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      child: Container(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.001),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
            initialChildSize: 0.4,
            minChildSize: 0.2,
            maxChildSize: 0.75,
            builder: (_, controller) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: const Radius.circular(25.0),
                    topRight: const Radius.circular(25.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.remove,
                      color: Colors.grey[600],
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        controller: controller,
                        itemCount: 100,
                        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                          return Card(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              child: Text("Element at index($index)"),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
 );
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted. It gives you more control

Comment: This is awesome and sexy.

Answer (score 30):

### If you want a model bottom sheet that can be scrolled.

You can use the `isScrollControlled` attribute of [showModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html) to achieve the effect.

---

### If you want a persistent bottom sheet that can be scrolled.

You can use the [DraggableScrollableSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html)

### Example:

```
    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('DraggableScrollableSheet'),
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
          builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.blue[100],
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: 25,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hgw819mL_78&feature=emb_title) is the official video from the Flutter team.

A live demo on DartPad can be found [here](https://dartpad.dev/a7b16f3910a7573103c65da6ba162448).

Comment: Does anyone know how to dismiss the DraggableScrollableSheet from the screen?

Comment: add a boolean variable, set its state based on a clickable event, ex: displayDSS ? DraggableScrollableSheet(...) : null

Comment: I have added this `isScrollControlled` but still, it is not scrollable.

Answer (score 15):

Almost the same solution like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66019404/7463972) but without the unnecessary layers of gesture detectors etc.

The important part is the `expand: false,` in `DraggableScrollableSheet`, because it defaults to true. This causes the bottom sheet to expand to full height in default config. With this set to false there is no need to wrap the bottom sheet with two gesture detectors to detect the outside tap.

Also in this case only one shape is required.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  isDismissible: true,
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius:
          BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(16))),
  builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
    initialChildSize: 0.4,
    minChildSize: 0.2,
    maxChildSize: 0.75,
    expand: false,
    builder: (_, controller) => Column(
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.remove,
          color: Colors.grey[600],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            controller: controller,
            itemCount: 100,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              return Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Text("Element at index($index)"),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This is perfect, thankyou very much for the example given.

Comment: I had problem with white space, setting expand to false fixed it, ty.

Comment: I like how you were able to improve on the already existing solution. Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
  initialChildSize: 0.4,
  minChildSize: 0.4,
  maxChildSize: 0.9,
  builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView(
        controller: scrollController,
        children: [
         
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do one thing wrap the child's you want to scroll in **Column**. Then return in **ListView.builder** and you can give Expanded as parent of **ListView.builder**.

Here is the example -

```
Epanded(
     child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 1,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               return Container(); //You can give whatever you want here});
```